# Django not returning the 'results template' in my Django tutorial

Tags: django, templates, url

I am using the web-poll app tutorial to understand the Django framework more.

In the tutorial after I create the vote method in the my polls/views.py and create the associated polls/templates/index.html, details.html, results.html templates, I am suppose to be presented with a question, 3 options to be selected using radio buttons and the vote button to submit my choice which is found in the details.html template.

After I select an option and click the vote button I am to see the number of times I voted for the specific choice in the results.html template.

In my polls/views.py file I have the vote method :

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)

    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

This is to ensure that when I vote I see the metrics and if I click the vote button without selecting a radio button then I will see the message * " You didn't select a choice."*

The issue is the above I am seeing this message even when I select a choice. How do I fix this.

These are the rest of files in polls/view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse



# Create your views here.

from .models import Choice,  Question 

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {  'latest_question_list': latest_question_list }
    return render( request, 'polls/index.html', context,);

def detail(request, question_id):
    try:
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question' : question})

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})
```

These are my templates :

Index.html

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
<ul>

    {% for question in latest_question_list %}

        <li><a href ={% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}>{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>

        {% endfor %}

</ul>


{% else %}
<p> No polls are available. </p>


{% endif %}
```

Detail.html

```
<h1> {{ question.question_text }} </h1>

{% if error_message %} <p><strong> {{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}




<form action = "{% url  'polls:vote'  question.id %}" method=" post ">

   {% csrf_token%}
   {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
   <input type = "radio" name = "choice" id = "choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{choice.id}}" />
<label for = "choice{{forloop.counter}}">{{ choice.choice_text }}

   </label>   <br/>

   {% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />

</form>
```

results.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>


    <ul>
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>




    <a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

Comment: What is the exact error if you remove the `except` block in the `vote` method?

Comment: @onyeka   This is part of the error:

Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/vote/?

Comment: this doesn't tell me much unfortunately beyond the fact that there's something wrong in your vote method. Need more of the traceback, or even the title of the error page.

Comment: @onyeka 

`Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  83.             list_ = super(MultiValueDict, self).__getitem__(key)

During handling of the above exception ('choice'), another exception occurred:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)`

Comment: `File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

`

Comment: `File "/Users/iivri.andre/website/polls/views.py" in vote
  29.     selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  85.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /polls/1/vote/
Exception Value: "'choice'"`

Comment: no answer :( having this exact same problem